# R - Finding words with same first and end letter using str_view()

Tags: r

Can someone please explain to me how this shows words that start and end with the same letter. Thank you!

`str_view(words, "^(.).*\\1$", match = TRUE)`

Comment: Two good place to start/learn regex : https://regex101.com/ , https://regexone.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses a *regular expression*, which can be broken down like this:

1. `^` means match the beginning of the line
2. `(.)` . means match anything, `()` means capture the result of the match
3. `.*` . means match anything. * means keep matching as you move along the string
4. `\\1` means the result of the first match that was captured (in step 1)
5. `$` means match the end of the line

So we capture the first letter after the start of the line, then match anything until we see that letter again at the end of the line.

Comment: Thank you so much!